# Issue with file sink and filename expression

Tags: spring-xd

Trying to set up simple file copy processin spring-xd:

```
 stream create --name mystrea --definition "file --dir=/path/source
--fixedDelay=5 | sink:file --dir=/path/dest --binary=true 
--name=headers['file_name']"
```

This seems to create and append fils to the file header['file_name'].out in the dest folder

Looking at sink:file definition

```
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="files"
            mode="${mode}"
            charset="${charset}"
            directory="${dir}"
            filename-generator-expression="'${name}' + '${extensionWithDot}'"/>
```

I see it puts '' around the name which causes it not to be evaluated.

Any suggestions besides create new sink:simplefile module that would do what I am looking for ? Am I missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the standard sink is not designed to do what you are trying to do (pass in an expression for the filename).

We should add an alternative property `--fileNameExpression=...` or similar.

In the meantime, you are correct, you'll need a custom sink (or modify the standard one).

I created a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2717) for this enhancement.